# Feature coordinates are in exact location in any GIS software but not in Mapbox. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: postgresql, mapbox, postgis

I have a feature in a postgreSQL database which I can load correctly into QGIS. However, when I load it in mapbox, it is offset by a few degrees in both latitude and longitude.

My database uses EPSG:32651 (WGS 84/UTM Zone 51N) as the reference system.

On my web application, I query the feature using this statement:

`SELECT *, ST_AsText(ST_Transform(geom,4236)) AS geometry FROM Schema.Table WHERE id = 1`;

so that the geometry is transformed into WGS84. I then load it to mapbox but it does not align perfectly. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: How many meters is the error?

Comment: It is shifted around 825 meters to the left and 200 meters up from where it's supposed to be.

Comment: It looks like choosing the wrong source SRS. 
Is your data located in Philippines? If so, try instead of EPSG:32651 any national SRS for Philippines - EPSG from 3121 to 3125 (PRS92, 5 zones) and EPSG from 25391 to 25395 (Luzor 1911, 5 zones).

Comment: https://epsg.io - here you can see envelope (boundary of territory) of each zone by EPSG code

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I finally found the solution. I was converting it to 4236 when mapbox is using 4326! What a stupid mistake on my part.